# Changing Collada material properties in THREE.js while keep the mapping

Tags: three.js, hierarchy, collada

Basically i want to change ambient and specular value of a collada object on the fly, while keeping the original texture. So i would like to have something like this:

```
var changeMaterial = function(node, ambient, specular) { 
    if (node.material != null) {
       var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
       material.clone(node.material);
       material.ambient = ambient;
       material.specular = specular;
       node.material = material;
    }   
    if (node.children) {
       for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
          setMaterial(node.children[i]);
       }
    }
}
```

After i tried this, ambient and specular seem to be changed but the texture is lost. What did i do wrong? Is there a methode to get the map so like:

```
material.map = node.material.map;
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new material? Just do this: `material.specular.set( 0x050505 )` or `material.specular.setRGB( .1, .1, .1 )`. `material.ambient` should in general match `material.color`.